# R plate validation

Tags: r, validation

I need to create a code in R that only allows entering only letters in the first three characters and only numbers in the last three characters, using something like the getch () function used in python. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grep` to validate a string where the first 3 characters are letters and the last three are digits

```
grepl("^[A-Za-z]{3}.*[0-9]{3}$", str1)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c('abced12', 'abcde123', 'bcd5')
```

Comment: How would I apply it to a plate entered by the user using readline ()?

Comment: @DanielRiaño you can use `str1 <- readline()` and then apply on `str1`

Comment: thanks, can you limit the number of characters to 6? that is, the user can only enter 6 characters.

Comment: @DanielRiaño yes, you can do `grepl("^[A-Za-z]{3}.*[0-9]{3}$", str1) && nchar(str1) == 6`

Comment: thank you very much, one last question, is there a way to use something similar to getch () (used in python) to enter each data check if it is number or letter? Would I have to use cycles?

Comment: ready, thanks for your help

Comment: @DanielRiaño that is very easy to check. `is.na(as.numeric(str1))` if it comes as TRUE, it is not a numeric one, FALSE means it is only numeric

Comment: str1 = readline(prompt= "ingrese la placa:")
str1 = as.integer(str1)
grepl("^[A-Za-z]{3}.*[0-9]{3}$", str1) && nchar(str1) == 6

Comment: @DanielRiaño the `as.integer` should be afterwards the `grep` step because if you do that before, and there are nonnumeric elements, it will be converted to `NA`

Comment: how would it look? I'm just starting at R and I wouldn't know how to do it

Comment: @DanielRiaño You created an object str1 `str1 = readline(prompt= "ingrese la placa:")`  Now, we do either a check if it is only a number with `!is.na(as.numeric(str1))`  TRUE for numeric and FALSE for character.  If you are further checking, then use `grepl` for the letters and numbers

Comment: Why does "Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion "?

Comment: @DanielRiaño  it is a friendly warning, when it coercces non-numeric to NA `v1 <- c('2', '3.5', '3a'); as.numeric(v1)`.  then, we make use of the  `is.na` to check for `NA` values

Comment: ah ok, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

Considering the token is a string, use stringr for splitting it.
library(stringr)

Then use this function:

```
letters_numbers <- function(token) {

# brake the string in separate letters for iteration
split_token <- list(strsplit(token,""))

check = 0   # check counter 1 for passed and 0 for failed

#take the first 3 letters and check if they are not numbers
    for (l in 1:3) {
        if (split_token[[1]][[1]][l] %in% c('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') == FALSE) {
        check = check + 1}
    }

    # take the last 3 letters and check if they are numbers
    for (l in 4:6) {
        if (split_token[[1]][[1]][l] %in% c('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')) {
        check = check + 1}
    }

    #Final Check if the token passed or failed. The sum needs to be 6, meaning all of the letters passed validation
    if (check == 6) {
        print('The token is valid')
    }
    else {
        print('The token is NOT valid')
      }
    }
```

My testing:
letters_numbers('abc123')
[1] "The token is valid"

letters_numbers('a1c123')
[1] "The token is NOT valid"

letters_numbers('1ab123')
[1] "The token is NOT valid"

letters_numbers('aab123')
[1] "The token is valid"